# BASH - Options included in $@

Tags: bash, getopts

I have a script that processes files and can take multiple file arguments:

`sh remove_engine file1 #single arg`

`sh remove_engine file1 file2 #multiple file arg`

At the top of the script, I gather these together with `$@` in order to loop over them.

The problem is that I'm also going to use options (along with `getopts`)...

`sh remove_engine -ri file1 file2`

...and `$@` now returns

`-rvi file1 file2`

and the rest of the script takes `-ri` as a file name.

Also near the top of the script, I have a while loop with `getopts`

```
while getopts :rvi opt
do
    case"$opt" in
    v)      verbose="true";;
    i)      interactive="true";;
    r)      recursive="true";;
   [?])     echo "Usage..."
            exit;;
    esac
done
```

How do I parse the options and then separate out the arguments from the options?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From `man bash`:

> When the end of options is encountered,  `getopts`  exits  with  a
>   return  value  greater than zero.  `OPTIND`is set to the index of
>   the first non-option argument, and `name` is set to `?`.

So the full code is:

```
#!/bin/bash

while getopts :rvi opt; do
  case $opt in
    v) verbose=true ;;
    i) interactive=true ;;
    r) recursive=true ;;
    *) echo "Usage..."; exit 1 ;;
  esac
done

shift $((OPTIND-1))  # remove all the OPTIND-1 parsed arguments from "$@"

echo "$@"  # use the remaining arguments
```

Comment: ... and note well that `getopts` expects all options (and their arguments, if any) to appear before any non-option arguments.  It will not recognize or return options that appear after a non-option argument.

Comment: @JohnBollinger That's true. The "first non-option argument" is the only "segregator".

Comment: `OPTIND` is set to the index of the first non-option argument, so `shift $OPTIND` will remove the options *and* the first non-option argument from the arg list. You want `shift $(($OPTIND-1))`, which will remove just the options, and leave all non-option arguments in the list.

Comment: @GordonDavisson Thanks, you're right, I've updated the answer.